# Why is this easeOutCubic returning larger jumps in change at the beginning and smaller at the end?

Tags: javascript, easing

I think i'm using this easing function wrong. Ease out functions should return larger changes to start, but I'm getting bigger jumps towards the end:

```
//Current value = Change
25 = 0
27.227575000000005 = 2.227575000000005
31.63817500000001 = 4.410600000000006
38.187700000000014 = 6.549525000000003
46.83250000000002 = 8.644800000000004
57.52937500000003 = 10.696875000000013
70.23557500000004 = 12.70620000000001
84.90880000000004 = 14.673225000000002
101.50720000000004 = 16.598399999999998
```

What am i doing wrong?

*What I want:*

1. It should start at 25 (25%, but I use the integer 25)
2. It should end at 100 (it's ok that it goes over as I'll limit it to 100 max)
3. It should start fast and end slow

https://jsfiddle.net/pqLddvzo/1/

```
function easeOutCubic(t, b, c, d) {
  t /= d;
  t--;
  return c*(t*t*t + 1) + b;
}

var x = 25;
var i = 0;
while ( x < 100 && i < 500 )
{
    let last = x;

    //Calculate our new percentage
    x = easeOutCubic( i, x, 75, 100 )

    //The new value and the change in value
    console.log( x + " = " + ( x - last ) );

    //move to next step
    i++;
}

//Also, why doesn't it take the full number of steps?
console.log( i );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that I was passing the value returned back into the next call as the "original" value:

```
x = easeOutCubic( i, x, 75, 100 );
```

Instead it should be:

```
x = easeOutCubic( i, 25, 75, 100 )
```

That field needs to remain unchanged. Only the first parameter should change on each call.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something with `Math.sqrt()`

```js
// Given a scale function that accepts whatever and return a number between 0 and 1
// Returns a function that accepts the same whatever and returns a number between min and max
function mapScale(scale, min, max) {
  return (...args) => {
    const original = scale(...args);
    return min + (original * (max - min));
  };
}

// Accepts a number between 0 and 1
// Returns a mapped number between 0 and 1
function sqrtScale(n) {
  n = Math.min(1, Math.max(n, 0)); // stay within the borders of 0 and 1
  return Math.sqrt(n);
}

const sqrtScaleBetween25And100 = mapScale(sqrtScale, 25, 100);

for (let i = 0; i < 1; i = i + .1) {
  console.log(sqrtScaleBetween25And100(i));
}
```

Note how the first 5 make up 50 units, and the last 5 only 25. You can make a steeper curve by applying a stronger root, for instance, `n ** (1/3)` or event `Math.sqrt(Math.sqrt(n))`

Comment: It's easier to reason about scales if they accept 0..1 and return 0..1, you can then change the domain (input) and range (output) as much as you like with modifier functions like `mapScale()`.